# unable to add a hyperlink dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `href` to `<a>` using jquery in this way

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var links = [
  {
    "_id": "57448a261f3e6161b34739f2",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "57448a2663568bbfc9dafe74",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "57448a26db2fbfa5cd38731f",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "57448a2650e28fbe8e2d87b3",
    "index": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": "57448a26a5e9ec8bd78c9809",
    "index": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": "57448a26fa772d6314ddc059",
    "index": 5
  },
  {
    "_id": "57448a26ba5a1782ae7c14af",
    "index": 6
  }
];

  for(var i in links){

    $('#link-list').append(
        $('<li>').append( 
          $('<span>').append(
          $('<a href="https://www.my-domain.so/goto?link-id="'+i+'></a>').html(i)
            ),
          $('</span>')
        ),
        $('</li>')
    );

  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="link-list"></ul>
```

I want to have result as

```
https://www.my-domain.so/goto?link-id=0
https://www.my-domain.so/goto?link-id=1
.
.
.
https://www.my-domain.so/goto?link-id=n
```

but *in vain*, please suggest the correct way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

There is misplaced `"` in your code, you were closed `href` tag just before the concatenate `i`.

```
$('<a href="https://www.my-domain.so/goto?link-id='+i+'"></a>').html(i)
//                                moved to here--------^-------------
```

---

Also there is an another bug that you are using `$('</span>')` and `$('</li>')` which are not valid selector or html creator. I think you are trying to enclose the tags. Actually there is no need of it for more info visit : http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes.

Check the updated snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var links = [{
    "_id": "57448a261f3e6161b34739f2",
    "index": 0
  }, {
    "_id": "57448a2663568bbfc9dafe74",
    "index": 1
  }, {
    "_id": "57448a26db2fbfa5cd38731f",
    "index": 2
  }, {
    "_id": "57448a2650e28fbe8e2d87b3",
    "index": 3
  }, {
    "_id": "57448a26a5e9ec8bd78c9809",
    "index": 4
  }, {
    "_id": "57448a26fa772d6314ddc059",
    "index": 5
  }, {
    "_id": "57448a26ba5a1782ae7c14af",
    "index": 6
  }];

  for (var i in links) {
    $('#link-list').append(
      $('<li>', {
        html: $('<span>', {
          html: $('<a>', {
            href: "https://www.my-domain.so/goto?link-id=" + links[i].index,
            text: i
          })
        })
      })
    );
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="link-list"></ul>
```

---

You can see those codes difference from the following image

[image]

`$('</span>')` is simply returns an empty jQuery object, where `</span>` act as a selector. And `$('<span>')`( or `$('<span/>')` ) creates a new element  which includes the closing tag itself. Also you can use `$('<span></span>')` to create an element. For more about [creating new elements using jQuery visit here](http://creating-new-elements).

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm horrified that `$('</span')),$('</li>')` works at all without the browser breaking down and crying...It's not my down-vote, but please: don't encourage that kind of atrocity, at least explain why it's a horrible, horrible approach.

Comment: it works because the browser makes the best of what you give it

Answer (score -1):

Try this peace of code..

https://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/qopbw0n2/

```
 for (var i in links) {
            $("<li/>")
        .append($("<span/>")
        .append($("<a/>").attr({ "href": "https://www.my-domain.so/goto?link-id=" + links[i]._id }).html(links[i].index)))
      .appendTo("#link-list");           
        }
```